# confluentinc/cp-zookeeper Docker Image and ZooKeeper's four letter word whitelist

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

ZooKeeper defines the Java property [4lw.commands.whitelist](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_clusterOptions) to enable certain four letter word commands. Using [Confluent's](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper) ZooKeeper Docker image, how can we specify values for this?

In "docker run", I've tried:

```
-e ZOOKEEPER_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST=stat
-e ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST=stat
```

But looking at the log, these have no effect. Only srvr is enabled.

Comment: Are you sure that container uses ZK 3.5.3? The first one is correct, though, if you exec into the container and look at the property file

Comment: Yeah, it's using v3.5.6. I tried the first one again but looking at /etc/kafka/zookeeper.properties I don't see the 4lw.commands.whitelist property. I tried adding it manually but it appears to re-create the file every time the container is restarted.

Comment: I assume this is your issue? https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the allowed properties in the Dockerfile to see that is not an allowed property - https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.3.1-post/debian/zookeeper/include/etc/confluent/docker/zookeeper.properties.template#L7-L30

The alternative, use `-e KAFKA_OPTS` to pass Java properties via `-Dzookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist`